# Avoid Bad Blood From Leaving Job

Tags: quitting

I recently moved to Seattle after completing a programming course to look for work. In the interim I started working at the gym near my apartment where I am a member.

When they hired me they asked if I was actively looking for another job. I said no because I wasn't really. I was putting in a pretty minimal effort after putting in a lot of effort with no results. So I was taking some time to work on my resume and develop some more skills.

However, my aunt asked for a copy of my resume so I obliged, which led to a phone interview at a large company. I feel pretty good about the interview, so I'm wondering what I should do about my current job. If it were any other stop-gap job, I would simply say something isn't working for me or my needs changed, but I like this gym and would like to continue as a member. The people here are friendly and supportive and I don't want to put them in a bind.

I have an in-person interview with the new company next week. If it results in an offer, what should I do to minimize any difficulties from leaving my current job so shortly after being hired? I was hired just over a month ago.

Comment: What are they out?  I bet you got like a few hours of training at best?

Comment: give them as much notice as you reasonnably can (once you have a formal offer) so they have the time to replace you. If people are hurt you can't really do anything, but if they like you they should be happy for you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming you did the programming course so you could work in IT, you could respond with something like:

> I got offered a role that is in line with my longer term career goals in IT.  I wasn't looking for a job, but it kind of fell in my lap.  I am really sorry, and I would like to continue to come to use the gym here.

No reasonable person will deny that you need to look after your own career path.  Unless you intend to stay working in gyms your whole career, then you would be rather silly to turn down something that takes you where you want to go!

Two more points:

- Don't mention anything to your current employer until you have a firm, formal offer.  You don't want to be caught with no chair when the music stops.
- Don't be surprised if they are not overjoyed.  Unfortunately that is part of life; you can't please all of the people all of the time!

Good luck!

Comment: I wouldn't say anything until I knew for sure but it's just been bugging me. I'm loyal to jobs to a fault (stayed at other jobs longer than I should have because it would have been inconveniencing them etc)

Comment: Really, it comes down to which is more important to you:  your career or not offending someone.  If it's the latter, let the job opportunity go and stay where you are.  If it's the former, then leave but be prepared for a little bit of potential bad blood.  But if they know you were looking for an IT job, I can't see them being to surprised that you took on.

Comment: @IanAuld beware of too much loyalty. Companies rarely return the favor when it's time to let employees go.